# Create Rails Schema from JSON Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

<del>Is it possible to</del> How can I generate a Rails schema from a JSON variable?

I'm looking to go from a JSON variable like this:

```
{
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
}
```

to having a Model called `Employee` with 2 fiels: `firstName` and `lastName`

Comment: Well, sure it's possible. However such questions are off-topic for stackoverflow. However if you show what you've tried to solve it and the problems you encountered that might be on-topic.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  As iceman has mentioned just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: You're using the term schema completely wrong. Schema means the specification of the columns of the database. Sort of like the blueprint of the database tables. What you want is to insert records into the database from JSON. Huge difference.

Comment: I have an incoming JSON variable that I want to use in a Rails app. I don't really see how it's off-topic, it seems like a pretty straight forward question. I thought someone may have done it before.

Comment: max: No, I'm not. I don't want to insert values, I want to create the schmea. I think you misread the question

Comment: Then its a absolutely horrible idea. If you want to store arbitrary structures use the JSON type column in Postgres or a nosql database like MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't generate schemas dynamically in a relational database. Even if its possible to monkey around and parse the JSON and use it to create SQL statements like:

```
CREATE TABLE 'employees' ...
```

Its just not an intelligent way to build web applications. It creates a ton of potential security issues and is not sane or maintainable.

It violates the entire way you should be using ActiveRecord - with migrations that build up the schema to a model that works for the problem domain.

If you want to store data in Postgres with an arbitrary schema use a JSON type column.

```
create_table :employees do |t|
  t.json 'data'
end
```

This will let you store whatever you want in `employees.data`.

Comment: I didn't want to generate schema dynamically